# onLocationChanged() working only 5.0.2?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

I am trying to fetch location using GPS_PROVIDER.its working perfectly fine in android version 5.0.2,but its not working other version.

i am providing code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GPSTracker.class));
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                2000, 1, this);
       // SeviceConnHandler serConHandler = new SeviceConnHandler(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
                + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned off!! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned on!! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.prajeeshthottathil.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    }
```

its perfectly working with NETWORK_PROVIDER.But in need to use only GPS.Let me know what i did wrong .

Comment: Try following this guide for fused location api which is suggested to obtain user's location by Google.
http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: its a offline app..working with out internet connection..is fused api will work off line?

Comment: Yes it does work without network connection. It's main advantage is that you don't need to mess with choosing location provider, it returns the location for given preferences.